# electron.js desktop app made with python as a back-end does not RUN ON any other pc than mine

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, electron

so i have recently made a CRUD software with python to connect to xampp database, but once i compile and distribute it, it run on my computer perfectly but when i share the setup file with another computer, it install properly but when you run the software, it shows the blue circle for 1-2 s and nothing opens.

Is there a problem with the SQL server or......

I am New to to develop an electron app, so guys go easy on me.

below if my package.json:

```
  "name": "nyota",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./web interface/main.js",
  "build": {
    "appId": "nyota"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "watch": "nodemon --exec electron .",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make",
    "dist": "electron-builder"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^19.0.1",
    "electron-builder": "^23.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Basically, after i run build for my CRUD desktop app, This app can only run on my pc because i have used phpmyadmin for my database and i have installed xampp, but a pc without these requirement (xampp for host serving) cannot run the app nor open it. so i am asking if its possible to package my sql database with my electronjs app and when another pc install it, they will be able to run it without error